# As a high level intuition, why is LWE without modular reduction easy to solve?

Tags: lwe

The LWE conjecture states that, given $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{m \times n}$ and $A x + e$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n, e \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ it's difficult to recover $x$, given that $e$ is sampled from a distribution concentrated around $0$. This might be a uniform distribution on $\{-\delta q, -\delta q+1, \dots, \delta q\}$ or a discrete Gaussian.

We could try working over the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_q$, also using a discrete Gaussian. However, this turns out to be insecure and, following [Bootle et al](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/822.pdf), one can use the least squares estimator and try to recover the secret value of $x$ that way.

The one thing that I'm missing is: why does that approach fail when we work modulo $q$? We could try to repeat the same algebra over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ that we decide over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is there any intuition why LWE is easy over  $\mathbb{Z}$ and hard over $\mathbb{Z}_q$?

For example, the intuition why dlog is easy over $\mathbb{Z}$ and hard over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is that we can "cheat" by using the ring structure of $\mathbb{Z}$, which we don't have in generic groups. Is there anything like that for LWE?

Comment: You are lucky, one of the authors is our [Mehdi Tibouchi](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/1423/mehdi-tibouchi)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to @Chao Sun's suggestion, let me propose the following handwavy explanation.

Let's say you collect samples by groups of $n$ each, so that you have a sequence of pairs $(A_i,b_i)$ with $b_i = A_i s + e_i$, where we can assume wlog that the A_i's are all invertible over $\mathbb{R}$. Then we have:
$$s = A_i^{-1} b_i - A_i^{-1} e_i = v_i + \varepsilon_i.$$
The errors $e_i$ are bounded, and for typical distributions of $A$, you can prove (using concentration results on the singular values of $A_i$) that the operator norm of $A_i^{-1}$ is also bounded with overwhelming probability. The expectation of $\varepsilon_i$ is zero by symmetry, so the law of large numbers shows that the average $\frac1k \sum_{i=1}^k \varepsilon_i$ tends to 0 when $k$ grows. It follows that the average of the first $k$ b_i's converges to $s$ for large $k$, which lets you recover $s$ exactly seeing as it has integer coefficients (just round once the error term is less than $1/2$ in infinity norm).

[Note that the above is not a particularly good algorithm to recover $s$, and it is much better to use e.g. least squares, or other suitable techniques depending on the specific distributons of $A$ and $e$, but this is for illustration purposes.]

The same idea would not work modulo $q$ for at least two reasons. First, as noted by @Chao Sun, since $A$ is normally chosen as uniform mod $q$, it is not the case that $A_i^{-1}$ will be “bounded” in a useful sense. Second, it is not true that averaging out “small values” mod $q$ yields another small value, contrary to what happens over $\mathbb{R}$, so the law of large numbers argument falls apart.

Of course, if you have sufficiently many samples, then it is true even mod $q$ that the pair $(A,b)$ determines $s$ uniquely in an information-theoretic sense. We just don't know any *efficient* algorithm to carry out the recovery (and known results on the hardness of LWE suggest that it would be extremely surprising if such an algorithm existed at all).

Comment: This is indeed a crucial observation that the LLN intuition falls apart mod q (or in any finite group): if $X_i \sim U(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $n \perp p$, then $\frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n}$ is again uniform, so we can't even hope for anything close to the LLN. (This can be generalized to any **finite** group). Thank you for the great answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is: it is impossbile to sample uniformly in \mathbb{Z}. Then b = As + e somehow concentrates. By comparison, sampling A in \mathbb{Z_q} makes b random in $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Comment: The error distribution is often chosen to be discrete gaussian even in the modulo q case.

Comment: Distribution of A matters a lot: if A is a binary matrix, this type of LWE (in the modular sense) is broken by May and Herold (https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/741). So maybe the answer is: if the standard deviation of A is too small compared with q, it is still insecure. If q becomes larger and larger, then we need larger std of A. In that sense, Z and Z_q makes no difference.